# What's the quickest and more efficient way to remove consecutive integers in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If I have a list like:
`infs = [0, 19, 20, 21, 24]`
I'd like to remove consecutive values but leave the first only from this group, so here I expect a result:
`infs = [0, 19, 24]`

My attempts:

```
 for k,(i,j) in enumerate(zip(infs, infs[1:])):
        print(k,i,j)
        if j-i == 1:
            del infs[k+1]
```

It leaves '21' because it was deleted, so this is bad idea to remove it in loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pair adjacent items in the list by zipping the list with itself but with a padding of its first item, so that you can use a list comprehension that filters out adjacent pairs that differ by just 1:

```
[b for a, b in zip(infs[:1] + infs, infs) if b - a != 1]
```

This returns:

```
[0, 19, 24]
```

Comment: If `infs` is a large list you might want to avoid the copy that `infs[:1] + infs` will make by using `chain(islice(infs, 1), infs)` instead (with `chain` and `islice` both coming from `itertools`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` over the enumeration of the given list, with a key function that returns the difference between the number and its index:

```
from itertools import groupby
[next(g)[1] for _, g in groupby(enumerate(infs), lambda t: t[1] - t[0])]
```

This returns:

```
[0, 19, 24]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You simply can do:**

```
infs=[0, 19, 20, 21, 24]
[v for (i, v) in enumerate(infs) if i==0 or v - infs[i-1] != 1]
```

> [0, 19, 24]